# How should I fetch every element that has an attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, queryselector

What would be the fastest and most efficient way to fetch every element that has an attribute?

Should I do this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[attr]').forEach((el) => {
  ...
});
```

Or this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((el) => {
  if (!el.hasAttribute('attr')) return;

  ...
});
```

Or something else completely.

Comment: [Which is faster?](//ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: the one that doesn't execute a function on every single element in the DOM is surely faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Selecting the elements** via the `querySelector('[attr]')` **is faster** than selecting all and check for certain constraints. It's much better readable and can be changed easier. (You can combine different selectors with it). Try here:

```js
console.log("Query all:")
console.time()
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((el) => {
  if (!el.hasAttribute('value')) return;
});
console.timeEnd()

console.log("Query [value]:")
console.time()
document.querySelectorAll('[value]').forEach((el) => {})
console.timeEnd()
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
<div value="hello"></div>
```